# Can someone explain this xargs command structure to me?

Tags: bash, xargs, inotify

This command is a part in a row of piped inotify workers (do you say that?) etc. I thought it would fit the one question per post policy better than asking for a dissection of the whole (very useful !) command to find out the used inotify

```
xargs -I '{}' -- ps --no-headers -o '%p %U %c' -p '{}'
```

According to the docs the syntax is

```
xargs [options] [command [initial-arguments]]
```

> -I replace-str
> Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-
> arguments with names read from standard input.  Also,
> unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the
> separator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L

Why are the braces in ticks?

Then the square brackets are filled with the output from `ps` command, right?

1. `--no-headers` - Is quite obvious
2. `-o` - Order option...
3. `%p` - process id (pid)
4. `%U` - user id
5. `%c` - simple name of executable

> -p pidlist
> Select by PID.  This selects the processes whose process
> ID numbers appear in pidlist.  Identical to p and --pid.

What does this second `'{}'` pid list do and what values does it have? `$foo` ? What does `select` mean in this context?

### Just for information

The preceding code is:

```
for foo in /proc/*/fd/*; do readlink -f $foo; done |grep inotify |cut -d/ -f3 |
```

Author: envygeeks , https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2082

Thanks

Comment: I can't work out where you are stuck. Tell us what you are stuck on.

Comment: There are issues with your "preceding code". (a) There are two race conditions that may throw errors: processes can vanish in the period between shell evaluating the wildcards, and readlink querying the link; and also before the ps can be run. (b) A process can have multiple files connected to inotify, so the same pid can be reported several times. I also think `-o` is the user-defined output format option, not the (BSD) ordering option.

Answer (score 0):

1. > Why are the braces in ticks?

   To prevent shell mangling it - in some shells it may be a special character sequence that will get interpreted; and you may decide to use something else than just `'{}'`.
2. > What does this second `'{}'` pid list do and what values does it have?

   The second `'{}'` is actually inside of the command that xargs will run - this is the place where `{}` will be replaced by whatever `xargs` reads on `stdin`
3. > $foo?

   No. Try to understand what the command generates loop over all open file descriptors (the `for` cycle) and get full path to them (the `readlink` part), which includes PID of the owning process. Then take this list, filter out those referring to inotify (the `grep` part) and extract the PIDs from paths (`cut`). Each line is what `xargs` uses as a replacement for the placeholder.
4. > What does select mean in this context?*

   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/select#Verb

Comment: The `-I '{}'` specifies the token in the `ps` command which will be substituted with the input value just read into xargs from stdin. The -I also has the effect of processing the input as lines, not words. `xargs` has no knowledge of the command it is going to run: it just merges the prototype command (starting with `ps`) with the variables from stdin (in this case they are process ids).